# How to avoid executing mysql queries in nested loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a bit of a problem with a task I was assigned.

I have this old phpmynewsletter database (MySQL backend).

Basically all emails are saved in a table with this structure:

```
    email   varchar(255)
    list_id int(11)
    hash    varchar(255)
    disclaimer1 tinyint(1)
    disclaimer2 tinyint(1)
    gender  char(1)
    dob date
    region  varchar(50)
```

So one same email can be present several times in the table, this is, subscribed in different newsletters (identified by **list_id**)

What I need to do is update the records so the fields **disclaimer1**, **disclaimer2**, **gender**, **dob** and **region** for a specific **list_id** are the same for the same **email** registered with other list_id's.

For example:

```
    email: email1(at)gmail.com
    list_id: 1
    disclaimer1: 0
    disclaimer2: 0
    gender: M
    dob: 1975-05-02
    region: Portugal
```

and

```
    email: email2(at)gmail.com
    list_id: 33
    disclaimer1: 1
    disclaimer2: 0
    gender: M
    dob: 1975-05-02
    region: Portugal
```

How do I update the record with list_id 33 with the correct values from record with list_id 1?

I'm using PHP and I believe that running updates queries in loops is bad practise. The table has around 610000 records.

Hope somebody can give me some insight on how to accomplish this task.

Thanks,
Mário

Comment: How will you provide the correct version? I mean if for a specific email, there are 10 lists it is subscribed in, which one should be chosen (and its data copied to the other 9)?

Comment: is this a one-time run or is it something that will have to be done continuously?

Comment: this question screams for a [groupwise max solution](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/groupwise-max/) in your update query, depending on which version of the data you want to use to update the other rows. (what ypercube already asked for clarification)

Comment: @ypercube For example if I'm comparing list_id 1 and list_id 33, I would like to keep the values from list_id 1.

Comment: @kaii In the groupwise max solution I don't understand what field would be used to MAX().

Comment: @mjpramos in this case, you would use the MIN() or MAX() `id` where email = "x@yz.com". Oh but i just realize you have no unique id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@bigman what you have posted seems to be right but I guess the question is on how to change all the other data similar to list_id: 1 with the same email.

```
UPDATE my_table t,
 (
    SELECT
        email,
        disclaimer1,
        disclaimer2,
        gender,
        dob,
        region
    FROM
        my_table
    WHERE
        list_id = 1
) t1
SET 
 t.disclaimer1 = t1.disclaimer1,
 t.gender = t1.gender,
 t.dob = t1.dob,
 t.region = t1.region
WHERE
   t.email = t1.email
```

I guess this should work for all the entries that would have the list_id: 1 email address.

Comment: Ya, don't copy my answer.  If you're going to put in a bad answer don't bother.  Both of the emails are the same, it will update the first one, then get to the second record and reupdate it back with the old information.  He would need an additional flag to figure out which ones need to be updated from the other, otherwise its a cluster F. Ending up with uncertain and VERY incorrect data.

Comment: @bigman actually this answer is more correct than yours. And what you critic is just not true, it would update all rows with the data from the row with `list_id = 1` instead of *the data of a random row mysql decides to select*, which depends on the version and engine used. as the behaviour for your `DISTINCT` solution is undefined.

Comment: @kaii, he's not trying to update 61,000 rows with the same data as id 1.  He wants every email to be updated down the line, automagically.

Comment: @Kaii thats an example.  He has multiple cirumstances.

Comment: @bigman no he isn't updating all 61,000 rows at once, and this query doesn't. It updates all rows *that have the same email address as the one with `list_id = 1`* with the data of that specific row. Assumed that not all 61,000 rows have the same email address (which is a safe assumption), this query might actually do what the OP requests-

Comment: read the damn title. "How to avoid executing mysql queries in nested loop?" if He puts in a 1, manually.  He's going to have to iterate through it after finding a list of all the people manually?

Comment: Hi! You guys are awesome! 
That's exactly what I needed @ngoa.

Comment: @all I am new so sorry for any misunderstandings or mistakes :)